# Get rows with blank value as text from python pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas, join, db2

I have this python code that pulls out some data from DB2 database into pandas dataframe data1 and data2. Data2 has a column named ARCD which has Text Values as '','01','03','14' etc.

```
TABLE1
    CSOFF      CSDATE
    ABC        20180101
    ADV        20180212
    AFS        20180121
    ADF        20180202
    ABC        20180115

TABLE2
    AROFF      ARAMT        ARCD      ARTRDT
    ABC        200                    20180101
    AFS        150          01        20180121
    ADV        210                    20180129
```

I need only those records in data3 where values in ARCD is blank i.e '', and '01'.

I can get all the values that have codes like '01', '03' etc. But I am not able to pull records with blank values, i.e ''.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
con = pyodbc.connect(
    driver='{iSeries Access ODBC Driver}',
    system='',
    uid='',
    pwd='')
cur = con.cursor()
query = """
SELECT * FROM QS99F.TABLE1 WHERE CSDATE > 20180100
"""
data1 = pd.read_sql(query,con,index_col = None)
query = """
SELECT * FROM QS99F.TABLE2 WHERE ARTRDT > 20180100
"""
data2 = pd.read_sql(query,con,index_col = None)
data3 = pd.merge(data1[['CSOFF','CSRATE']],data2[['AROFF','ARAMT','ARCD']],left_on=['CSOFF','CSMKT','CSSUFX'],right_on=['AROFF','ARMKT','ARSUFX'],how='inner')
dp = data3['ARCD'] == "01"
ar = data3['ARCD'] == ""
data3 = data3[dp|ar]
print (data3)
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. How is `data3[dp|ar]` not working?

Comment: data3[dp|ar] is working, its not picking records that are "" (blank). If I put anything in ar that is not "", then it works. So we cannot say that data3[dp|ar] is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that your blank values are actually `nan` rather than `""`.

You can change this as follows:

```
data3 = data3.fillna("")
```

before your tests.

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Thanks a lot @adr